# Showing no error but program is not running in pytest

Tags: python, selenium

**//This is Conftest.py file**

```
import pytest

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium import webdriver



option1=Options()

option1.add_experimental_option("prefs",{"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications":1})

print("setupfunction")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")

def setup(request):

    print("setupfunction")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\chrome\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe",options=option1)

    driver.get("https://web.comrate.com/")

    driver.maximize_window()

    request.cls.driver=driver

    yield

    driver.close()
```

**//This is baseclass.py file**

```
import pytest

import logging


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")

class baseclass:

    pass
```

**//this is Logintest.py file**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import pytest


class TESTLOGIN():

    def __init__(self,driver):

        self.driver=driver

    loginbutton=(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='btn btn-default'][@id='loginbtn']")

    emailaddress =(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='login_email']")

    password=(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='login_password']")

    logintoaccount=(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='btn btnDanger']")

    def testloginbutton(self):

        return self.driver.find_element(TESTLOGIN.loginbutton)

    def testemail(self):

        return self.driver.find_element(TESTLOGIN.emailaddress)

    def testpwd(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(TESTLOGIN.password)

    def testlogin(self):

        return self.driver.find_element(TESTLOGIN.logintoaccount)
```

**//this is main file**

```
import time

import pytest

from Logintest import TESTLOGIN

from baseclass import baseclass


class testloginfunction(baseclass):

    def testsign(self):

        #click loginbutton

        log=TESTLOGIN(self.driver)

        log.testloginbutton()

        time.sleep(5)

        log.testemail().sendkeys("hello")
```

while i am running main file, it shows **Process finished with exit code 0**  as it is not going into class or functions and i am not getting any results or browser invocation or anything else.

Comment: can you help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a class and a function but you're not using any as it seems to me in the main file, try to create an object for the testloginfunction and using the method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: new1=testloginfunction()
new1.testsign()                                                                                                                                                                  As you said, I have created object and called the method. now the below error is showing     'testloginfunction' object has no attribute 'driver'

Comment: The only thing you put as a local variable for the testloginfunction class has is the baseclass, which is empty itself, so it doesn;t have any driver yet you're passing one, you need to create a selenium webdriver in the testloginfunction to reference it that way, or create it in the baseclass, doesn't really matter, you just need to add an init like this :
```python
def init():
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\chrome\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe",options=option1)
```
or reuse the same one from the setup and remove the keyword "self"